# Incorrect frame values when using Stack Views

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9, uistackview

I have two images placed into a single stack view. I want to programmatically convert these two square images into circles, so I use the following code.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!

    override viewDidLoad(){
        // Convert image one into circle
        self.image1.layer.cornerRadius = self.image1.frame.height/2
        self.image1.clipsToBounds = true

        // Convert image two into circle
        self.image2.layer.cornerRadius = self.image2.frame.height/2
        self.image2.clipsToBounds = true

        // Print the frames of these two images
        print(self.image1.frame)
        print(self.image2.frame)
    }
}
```

In the examples, the x and y values of the frames don't matter, but oddly, the width and height values both end up being zero, despite the values on the inspector tab.

If I add a button on the screen that then prints out the frames of the two images, I get the expected width and height values. Therefore, I would assume that Stack Views determine the dimensions of the objects after the `viewDidLoad()` method fires. In this situation, what would be the best way to get the actual frame dimensions in order to round out the two images? Or would using a value other than frame be a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case since you are trying to access the frame of the image view and using UIStackView, the frame will actually first be laid out in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. So to get the rounded image you want, you would need to first make an outlet for the stack view as such:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalStackView: UIStackView!

    ...
```

Then in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method, access the index of the `arrangedSubviews` of your stack view to get the view where your image is at (index can be determined from the Stack View hierarchy, going top to bottom) and then get the rounded corner as you have been doing:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var verticalStackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let myImage = verticalStackView.arrangedSubviews[1] //in my test my image was the second view in the stack view hierarchy

        myImage.layer.cornerRadius = myImage.frame.height/2
        myImage.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: That did the trick! It was `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` that I hadn't discovered. Many thanks!